# How to make Excel Open Hyperlinks in IE (non-default browser) when table is filtered

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I've been racking my brain thinking of a solution when I have zero programming knowledge and neither aware of the basics of VBA and creating macros. I surfed the net for answers, and still could only come up with a subpar solution, so I'm asking for help.

My problem is this: I have an excel file which has a table, and that table has filters. For dates. Within that table, I have a column which is designated for links that I would like to open on IE (which is not my default browser, but it (IE) is for the company database that only works on IE).

The links have unique ID numbers assigned to them (on Column G) so the format is like http:// site(.)com/uniqueIDnumber (concatenated with the ID numbers from Column G) per link. What I would like to happen is to be able to filter the table by the relevant dates, so that when I click on the remaining hyperlinks (which I, by the way, concatenated), Excel would be prompted to open these concatenated links on Internet Explorer (no sign-in required).

So far, with my hours-long browsing, I've somehow managed to end up with this code (I have used a different site name for anonymity to protect data). What it does is open all links it finds on the designated column at once. Here it is:

```
Sub openurl()

Dim IELocation As String
Dim MyURL As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim FinalRowFiltered As Long

FinalRowFiltered = Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To FinalRowFiltered
MyURL = Sheet4.Cells(i, 7)

IELocation = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

Shell (IELocation & " http://tool.filings.irc.site.com/tool/" & MyURL)

Next i

End Sub
```

What I have managed to do with the code that I have (copied from youtube and google searching) is to open all links at once, which is disastrous (as you can imagine). I only need to open links according to what is left after I put the filters in place. Please let me know how I can resolve this. Thanks in advance!

Below is an image link provided for clarification. What is shown are columns A to I and rows 1-20

[image]

Comment: So if I’m understanding your post, you’re able concatenate the url, you just need to open it in IE and your Shell line is not working? One possible solution is making use of the InternetExplorer object. There a lot information floating around out there on how to use it. A search on this site should yield you a lot of information.

Comment: It looks like you have found the solution you need. You can mark it as an accepted answer, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the HYPERLINK() formula.

For example if you have "https://google.com/search?q=hyperlinks" in (eg) C2 and you have this formula in D2 then clicking on "View" will open the url from C2 using IE:

```
=HYPERLINK("#ShowInIE(""" & C2 & """)","View")
```

Put this function in a regular module

```vb
'This function called from worksheet HYPERLINK() formula
Function ShowInIE(url) As Range
    Dim ie As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ie = GetObject("", "InternetExplorer.Application") 'get open iE?
    On Error GoTo 0
    'if was not open then open a new instance
    If ie Is Nothing Then Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate url
    Set ShowInIE = Selection 'must do this in a function called from a hyplerlink
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! This was EXACTLY what I was looking for! Solution worked perfectly! Coupled with enabling Microsoft Internet Controls from @Dennaldo

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed and after doing @dennaldo 's suggestion to enable Microsoft Internet Controls :) Thank you thank you thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

So if I’m understanding your post, you’re able to concatenate the URL, you just need to open it in IE and your Shell line is not working?

One possible solution is making use of the InternetExplorer object. There a lot information floating around out there on how to use it. A search on this site should yield you a lot of information.

A basic use case to open a URL would be something like this:

```
Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer
ieApp.Visible = True
‘url is your concatenated url variable
ieApp.Navigate url
```

Go to References and enable Microsoft Internet Controls in order to use the object.